# How to set the time zone for a date in iOS 3.x

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsdate, nstimezone

Anyone know how to set the time zone in an NSDate object prior to iOS 4.0? In iOS 4 and greater I do the following:

```
NSCalendar *calendar = [[[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar] autorelease];
NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:(NSYearCalendarUnit|NSMonthCalendarUnit|NSWeekdayCalendarUnit|NSDayCalendarUnit|NSHourCalendarUnit|NSMinuteCalendarUnit|NSSecondCalendarUnit|NSTimeZoneCalendarUnit) fromDate:aDate];
NSTimeZone *gmt = [NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0];
[components setTimeZone:gmt];
NSDate *newDate = [calendar dateFromComponents:components];
```

Problem is, setTimeZone and NSTimeZoneCalendarUnit are only available starting with iOS 4.0. Will I have to do a subtraction on the hours component?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NSCalendar has the method `setTimeZone:`

Available in iOS 2.0 and later.

Sets the time zone for the receiver.

```
- (void)setTimeZone:(NSTimeZone *)tz
```

Example:

```
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
[calendar setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"America/Jamaica"]];
NSLog(@"calendar timezone: %@", calendar.timeZone);
```

NSLog output:

> calendar timezone: America/Jamaica (EST) offset -18000

or with a timezone offset:

```
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
[calendar setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0]];
NSLog(@"calendar timezone: %@", calendar.timeZone);
```

NSLog output:

```
calendar timezone: GMT (GMT) offset 0
```

Comment: That's on NSCalendar, not NSDate.

Comment: @Bored: `NSDate`s don't have time zones.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `setTimeZone:` on the `NSCalendar` object.